# What is the name of the background music that plays before Kaori and Kousei's performance?

Tags: music, your-lie-in-april

In Episode 4, right before their performance, Kaori headbutts Kousei, and then some BGM starts playing. In the next episode, episode 5, as Kousei is running home in the rain, the same song plays again, and continues into the flashback. What is the name of the song?

I've transcribed the first part of the song, it gets pretty inaccurate towards the end but should still be recognizable.

http://www.noteflight.com/scores/view/e958304d60b8f1a61108335f228623a5e0084cef

Comment: It most likely is an original song for the anime. [The official site](http://www.kimiuso.jp/music/) links [here](http://www.kimiuso-ongakucho.com/), and it is not one of the songs there (I didn't listen to all of them integrally, so it could be some random part halfway through any song, but I doubt this).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding to [my previous comment on the question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/14761/what-is-the-name-of-the-background-music-before-the-performance/18728#comment19205_14761), the official website now has [a page for the **"Your Lie in April original song & soundtrack"** (「四月は君の嘘 ORIGINAL SONG & SOUNDTRACK」)](http://www.kimiuso.jp/music/soundtrack2.html). They have a full listing of the soundtrack there, but you cannot listen to it, nor even preview it.
So I did a quick search, and found [this Amazon.co.jp page for the cd](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%9B%9B%E6%9C%88%E3%81%AF%E5%90%9B%E3%81%AE%E5%98%98-ORIGINAL-SONG-SOUNDTRACK-TV%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9/dp/B00PB88GH0), where you can actually listen to a preview of every song.

Three songs seem to fit the one you want, given that two of them are only variations on the same theme. The one that does seem to be the exact match is called **友人A君を私の伴奏者に任命します** (something in the lines of "I appoint Friend-A-kun as my accompanist"), and is the 18th track on the first cd. You can buy it individually [here](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/B00S1QQ1U8/ref=dm_mu_dp_trk18). The first variation is the 12th track on the first cd, called **今日のことは忘れられないよ** (something like "I cannot forget that day"), which, once again, can be bought individually [here](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/B00S1QPSMU/ref=dm_mu_dp_trk12). And the last one is 7th track on the second cd (or the 40th if you count them continuously, like Amazon does), called **分かりやすいヤツ** (something like "Easy-to-understand guy"), which can also be bought individually, [here](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/B00S1QQYVO/ref=dm_mu_dp_trk40)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoSnwZ7dGAk) will help you.

If this is indeed the song you are looking for I'm afraid I can't help further than this. I tried to find the original song but I failed.

It seems that the name given to the song in this particular video is not its original name, as the description points out:

> I decided to give a name for this BGM, as the title would've gone over
>   100 characters if I had used "Composed by Masaru Yokoyama". So I named
>   it Spring's Melody. I don't know if there is an actual name for this
>   BGM...if there is, would you please tell me :3?

---

EDIT: The song is called ***Yuujin A-kun wo Watashi no Bansousha ni Ninmeishimasu*** and you can find it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IcYJHojTsFg)
.

Comment: Thanks, that video is someone playing a cover of the song after transcribing it. Transcribing is what I did in order to  get the link in my original post. Playing a cover is when someone plays someone else's work. Essentially anyone playing classical music is playing a cover unless they wrote the song themselves. Either way, the video isn't the answer to my question, but it's still very helpful since I was asking in order to get the sheet music.