# What is the background music in Your Lie in April that starts from 14:45 min in episode 4?

Tags: your-lie-in-april

I've searched everywhere but couldn't find this music. It starts from 14:45 min in episode 4.

Comment: Is this the piano music that starts when we cut to Kaori's monologue about what she wants to do as a musician? The time-stamp seems slightly off; you might want to add a detail about the scene so it's clearer. In any case, if it's that, it sounds like an original composition.

Answer (score 3):

As with [this other answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/18728/49), I was able to find the right song in [this Amazon.co.jp page for the soundtrack](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%9B%9B%E6%9C%88%E3%81%AF%E5%90%9B%E3%81%AE%E5%98%98-ORIGINAL-SONG-SOUNDTRACK-TV%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9/dp/B00PB88GH0), where you can listen to a 30-second preview of every song.

The song in question is track 26 of the first CD, **アゲイン** — meaning "again," what Kaori says at minute 15:04 to Kousei. You can buy the song individually [here](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00S1QQECI/ref=pm_ws_tlw_trk26).

You can buy the full album in the Amazon page linked to above, but also from [the show's official page](http://www.kimiuso.jp/music/soundtrack2.html) if you'd prefer.