# What is the piano song that was played around minute 9 of episode 11?

Tags: your-lie-in-april

What is the song (piano) that was played around the ninth minute of episode 11?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the music is the same one that plays [on episode 4, around the 14:45 mark](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/38406/49):

> The song in question is track 26 of the first CD, **アゲイン** — meaning "again," (...). You can buy the song individually [here](https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B00S1QQECI/ref=pm_ws_tlw_trk26).
>
> You can buy the full album in the Amazon page linked to [below], but also from [the show's official page](http://www.kimiuso.jp/music/soundtrack2.html) if you'd prefer.

As with my other answers on finding songs for this series, I was able to find the right song in [this Amazon.co.jp page for the soundtrack](http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E5%9B%9B%E6%9C%88%E3%81%AF%E5%90%9B%E3%81%AE%E5%98%98-ORIGINAL-SONG-SOUNDTRACK-TV%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%A9/dp/B00PB88GH0), where you can listen to a 30-second preview of every song.